# How do I pass C compiler flags in a Haskell Stack package.yaml

Tags: haskell, ffi, haskell-stack

I'm working on a Haskell project involving some FFI, and I keep making small typos in the names of C functions in my Haskell code, which due to implicit function declaration, results in a warning, but not an error.

I'd like to pass `-Werror-implicit-function-declaration` to the gcc arguments, in order to turn these warnings into errors.

I'm using Haskell Stack, and it's not obvious to me what I ought to add to my `package.yaml` in order to do this? What field should I add?

Comment: Let me check, I'm pretty sure I have some local projects somewhere that do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at some of my local projects, here's one example:

```
library:
    exposed-modules:
    - ...
    source-dirs:
    - ...
    ghc-options:
    - ...
    pkg-config-dependencies:
    - glib-2.0
    extra-lib-dirs:
    - /Workspace/INSTALL/lib
    include-dirs:
    - ./native
    - /Workspace/INSTALL
    c-sources:
    - ./native/*.c
    cc-options:
    - -O3 -fPIC -g3 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-variadic-macros -Werror
```

You can find the full reference documentation at https://github.com/sol/hpack.

Comment: I'm going to accept/upvote this, because it's _right. But I wasn't actually able to get the behaviour I wanted until I added `cpp-options: -Werror-implicit-function-declaration`. This makes little sense to me, because as I understand it `cpp-options` are for pre-processor options, and stack even reports `Warning: 'cpp-options': -Werror-implicit-function-declaration is not portable
C-preprocessor flag`

Comment: @Joe Hmm, that's quite interesting.  I copied the above from some older project that I did about a year ago.  The `-fPIC` was really the crucial part of it, everything else was mostly cosmetic.  I haven't worked on that project for a long time, but figured it'd be best to use a concrete sample from something that I knew had worked in the past.

Comment: 6 months later, I finally understand why I was seeing some weirdness: I had some c++ code in my `c-sources`, (as opposed to `cxx-sources`), and the compiler for the c++ code did not seem to be passed either the `cc-options` or the `cxx-options`, moving the c++ code under `cxx-sources` seems to make everything behave